# Does fat help or hinder bowel movements?

Tags: constipation

I have found sources saying that fat promotes bowel movements
[Why a High Fiber Diet is Killing Your Colon ( And Why a LOW Fiber Diet Will Help Constipation & IBS) - Modern Health Monk](https://modernhealthmonk.com/low-fiber-diet/)
[Association between Dietary Factors and Constipation in Adults Living in Luxembourg and Taking Part in the ORISCAV-LUX 2 Survey - PMC](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8746799/)
[5 common reasons of constipation (not eating fat is one of them)](https://dietideas.com.my/constipation/)
[Why Your Healthy New Diet Is Making You Constipated | U.S. News](https://health.usnews.com/wellness/food/articles/why-your-healthy-new-diet-is-making-you-constipated)
[Beware! Your Fad Diet May Be Causing Irregular Bowel Movements](https://www.ndtv.com/health/beware-your-fad-diet-may-be-the-reason-of-your-irregular-bowel-movements-1922962)

I have also found sources saying that fat hinders bowel movements.
[Association of High Dietary Saturated Fat Intake and Uncontrolled Diabetes with Constipation: Evidence from the National Health and Nutrition Examination Survey (NHANES)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4584183/) 
[Foods for Constipation | Johns Hopkins Medicine](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/wellness-and-prevention/foods-for-constipation) 
[Concerned About Constipation? | National Institute on Aging](https://www.nia.nih.gov/health/concerned-about-constipation) 
[Worst Foods for Constipation](https://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/ss/worst-foods-for-constipation) 
Which is it?

Comment: The answer to this question is almost certainly going to be "it depends," and that's exactly what all those articles illustrate; ie, fat increases constipation under _some_ circumstances for _some_ people, and decreases it under other conditions. There are very few black/white, yes/no answers in medicine, especially when it comes to diet and nutrition, and this isn't one of those few.

Comment: First, apples to apples. Your references are all over the place medically; people with IBS, the elderly, diabetics, etc. Second, agree with @CareyGregory. Determining the effects of food consumption in humans is incredibly difficult/fraught with hazards due to large self-reporting inaccuracies, unknown differences in gut microbiomes, genetic factors, and a host of other differences between people, many known and more yet to be discovered.